# Log in to website and retrieve data from the page

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

So I'm making a script that gets info from a page that you can see and retrieve data from it using BeautifulSoup, but to get the data from the main page you need to log in. How do I log in and retrieve data from the page it sends me to for parsing in BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Where a you trying to get this info from?

Comment: You're probably looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24805764/2487476

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requests_ntlm`.

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

r = requests.get("http://protected_site.com",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password'))

soup = r.text
print soup
#print soup.prettify()) or whatever bs4 stuff you want to do
```

1. Replace *protected_site.com* with the domain  of the site you want to get info from
2. Replace the "domain" and "username" with the appropriate values while keeping the `\\` in between them.
3. Change `print soup` to whatever wonderful `bs4` task you have in mind.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LoginTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    print soup
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 18105-18
106: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @CrazyClyde is that from printing r.text or using beautiful soup?

Answer (score 0):

before login to website it require cookies and server require user-agent to login to site so i think this will help 
            [python programm to log into the web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258042/python-programm-to-log-into-the-web-page/26566377#26566377)